# Handle all unicodeDecodeerror in python 3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os, fnmatch
    def findReplace(directory, find, replace, filePattern):
      for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(directory)):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, filePattern):
            filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
            enc='utf-8'
            with open(filepath,"r",encoding=enc) as f:
                s = f.read()
                try:
                    s = s.encode("iso-8859-1").decode("utf-8")
                except (UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeDecodeError):
                    pass
            s = s.replace(find, replace)
            with open(filepath, "w",encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore' ) as f:
                f.write(s)



def main():

    mylist = [ ("findstring", "replacestring")]
    for item in mylist:
        findReplace('.', item[0], item[1], '*.*')

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I am trying to search and replace a string in all files inside the given folder. 
Folder has all kinds of files and its window server. 
I am using python 3.0. How do I avoid the Unicodedecode error?

Comment: Does this code throw an exception? Does the exception have a line number? Please include the traceback.

Comment: I was getting - codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0] in f.read()